# How to unit test active record pattern static methods?

Tags: php, unit-testing, activerecord, mocking, yii2

I'm wondering how I would go about unit testing the active record pattern?  I'm using Yii 2 for this project and I understand that normally I would want to make mocks and use dependency injection to insert these mocks into my test class - however, I don't see how I would do this with static methods since I'm not instantiating the class anywhere?  For example, in Yii's active record class I would do the following to select a row from the database: 
`ExampleTable::find()->where(['id' => 10])->one();`

Any ideas how I would mock this class that uses static methods to work directly with the database?

Answer (score 3):

In Yii2 exist `codeception` and you can use library `codeception/AspectMock` to mock all static without dependency injection:

https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock

This is example from official AspectMock manual:

> Allows stubbing and mocking of static methods.
>
> Let's redefine static methods and verify their calls at runtime.

```
<?php 
function testTableName() 
{
     $this->assertEquals('users', UserModel::tableName());   
     $userModel = test::double('UserModel', ['tableName' => 'my_users']);
     $this->assertEquals('my_users', UserModel::tableName());
     $userModel->verifyInvoked('tableName');  
}
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas:

- extract db related stuff to some kind of Repository/DAO class, inject it as a dependency and mock in your test
- extract db related stuff to separate methods visible in tests and use partial mocking
- go with tests that actually use db, so prepare your data as a part of test setup, run method and verify results based on what was returned from db -> however it may not comply with your unit test definition :)